# jQuery this function

Tags: jquery

```
$('.delivery_option').click(function() {
    var current = $('.active-radio-label');
    if (current.length)
        current.removeClass('active-radio-label');
    $(this).addClass('active-radio-label');

    $(this).('.delivery_option span').addClass('checked');
});
```

I have a problem with the last line `$(this).('.delivery_option span').addClass('checked');`

I am trying to point to the `span` that is in `.delivery_option` class. After someone click `.delivery_option`

HTML:

```
    <div class="delivery_options">
  <div class="delivery_option item">
    <div>
      <table class="resume table table-bordered resp_table ">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="delivery_option_radio">
              <div class="radio" id="uniform-delivery_option_1349_0"><span><input type="radio" value="199," data-id_address="1349" data-key="199," name="delivery_option[1349]" class="delivery_option_radio" id="delivery_option_1349_0"></span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="delivery_option_logo">
              <img alt="Odbiór osobisty" src="/img/s/199.jpg" class="order_carrier_logo">
            </td>
            <td class="white_space_normal">
              <strong>Odbiór osobisty</strong>
              <br>&nbsp;- sklep Konstantynów Łódzki
            </td>
            <td class="delivery_option_price">
              <div class="delivery_option_price">
                Za darmo!
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end delivery_option -->
  <div class="delivery_option alternate_item">
    <div>
      <table class="resume table table-bordered resp_table ">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="delivery_option_radio">
              <div class="radio" id="uniform-delivery_option_1349_1"><span class="checked"><input type="radio" checked="checked" value="205," data-id_address="1349" data-key="205," name="delivery_option[1349]" class="delivery_option_radio" id="delivery_option_1349_1"></span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="delivery_option_logo">
              <img alt="Inpost / DPD" src="/img/s/205.jpg" class="order_carrier_logo">
            </td>
            <td class="white_space_normal">
              <strong>Inpost / DPD</strong>
              <br>&nbsp;- przelew
            </td>
            <td class="delivery_option_price">
              <div class="delivery_option_price">
                16,00 zł (brutto) </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end delivery_option -->
  <div class="delivery_option item">
    <div>
      <table class="resume table table-bordered resp_table ">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="delivery_option_radio">
              <div class="radio" id="uniform-delivery_option_1349_2"><span><input type="radio" value="206," data-id_address="1349" data-key="206," name="delivery_option[1349]" class="delivery_option_radio" id="delivery_option_1349_2"></span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="delivery_option_logo">
              <img alt="Inpost / DPD" src="/img/s/206.jpg" class="order_carrier_logo">
            </td>
            <td class="white_space_normal">
              <strong>Inpost / DPD</strong>
              <br>&nbsp;- za pobraniem
            </td>
            <td class="delivery_option_price">
              <div class="delivery_option_price">
                27,00 zł (brutto) </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end delivery_option -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the `span` element and then add class.

```
$(this).find('span').addClass('checked');
```

I think you need

```
$('.delivery_option').click(function() {
    var current = $('.active-radio-label');
    if (current.length){
       current.removeClass('active-radio-label')
            .find('sapn') //Find span descendant
            .removeClass('checked'); //remove class
    }

    $(this).addClass('active-radio-label').find('span').addClass('checked');
});
```

Comment: If the span is always going to be a direct descendant, .children() would be better than .find().

Comment: @MCMXCII We're unsure where the span is in the html so using find method is okay.

Answer (score 2):

You just need

```
$(this).find('span').addClass('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , it will work

```
    jQuery('.delivery_option').click(function() {
        var current = jQuery('.active-radio-label');
        if (current.length)
            current.removeClass('active-radio-label');
        jQuerythis).addClass('active-radio-label');

        jQuery(this).('.delivery_option span').addClass('checked');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this below it seems to work but it dont make input clicked. It olny change the class. Maybe i shpuld use `.click();` on input ?

```
    <script>
$('.delivery_option').click(function() {
    var current = $('.active-radio-label');
    if (current.length)
        current.removeClass('active-radio-label');
    $(this).addClass('active-radio-label');

    $('.delivery_option').find("span").removeClass('checked')

    $(this).find("span").addClass('checked');
});
</script>
```